# How to display loading widget until a main widget is loaded

Tags: flutter, dart, animation, flutter-layout

I am using the animation package to create a popup modal However building the widget inside the model is very noticeably slow and is making making the popup take time to open. I am trying to put a loading indicator when opening the modal then build the widget afterward and just update.

I am lost on how to accomplish that.. it would be highly appreciated if someone could help.

this is the animation package method for the modal

```
ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    showModal<void>(
                      context: context,
                      builder: (BuildContext context) {

                          // building _ExampleAlertDialog takes time
                        return _ExampleAlertDialog(loading: loading);
                      },
                    ).then((state) => setState(() => {loading = !loading}));
                  },
                  child: const Text('SHOW MODAL'),
                ),
```

the `_ExampleAlertDialog` is supposed to be  a listView

```
class _ExampleAlertDialog extends StatefulWidget {
  _ExampleAlertDialog({
    this.loading,
  });
  final bool loading;
  @override
  __ExampleAlertDialogState createState() => __ExampleAlertDialogState();
}

class __ExampleAlertDialogState extends State<_ExampleAlertDialog> {


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 50, horizontal: 20),
      child: Expanded(
        child: ClipRRect(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
          child: Material(
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      border: Border(
                          bottom: BorderSide(
                              color: Theme.of(context).dividerColor))),
                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10, horizontal: 12),
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: [Icon(Icons.arrow_back), Icon(Icons.refresh)],
                  ),
                ),

// This is the Listview I am trying to avoid onLoad

                Expanded(child: widget.loading == true ? Container(): 
                      ListView.builder(
                      itemCount: 16,
                      itemBuilder: (BuildContext ctxt, int index) {
                        return Container(
                          // width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 1,
                          child: Row(
                            children: <Widget>[
                              Icon(
                                Icons.radio_button_unchecked,
                                color: Colors.blue,
                                size: 12.0,
                              ),
                              SizedBox(
                                width: 20.0,
                              ),
                              Text(
                                "Travetine",
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.black,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w400),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        );
                      },
                    )
                    )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Which part inside StatefulWidget `_ExampleAlertDialog` cause this slow? I didn't see any asynchronous data need to be wait so it could me some kind of performance issue?

Comment: the `listView.builder` inside `_ExampleAlertDialog` is the one causing the slow. it takes time to build that is why putting a loading widget and building it after the popup opens would be better. I can't figure a way to do it though @yellowgray

Comment: The `listView.builder` shouldn't be the bottleneck in your provided code... I wonder the bottleneck is somewhere else.What animation package did you use? Do you use any asynchronous data inside `ListView` ?  What currently result you see now?

Comment: I am not sure how powerful the emulator you are using is, but replace the `listView.builder` with empty container , you should feel the difference in the opening and closing of the popup. the difference is noticeble on low end divices. right now I am not even using async data it's just hard coded `listView.buider` data. @yellowgray

Comment: I am using [animation package](https://pub.dev/packages/animations). @yellowgray

Comment: Here is my result:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/461rq.gif.